# Как остановить рекурсию?

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, парсер

Создаю модуль на Python по нахождению указанного типа файла (.jpg, .dll, .mp4) в указанной директории. 
Мой код:

```
 import os
 import sys
 import time

 time.sleep(0.3)


 def walker(directory, access):
     for name in os.listdir(directory):
         path = os.path.join(directory, name)
         check = os.path.basename(path)
         if os.path.isfile(path):
             if check[len(check)-4:] == access:
                print('[found] ' + str(access) + ' file   ' + path)

             else: walker(path, access)


 if __name__ == '__main__':
      walker('C:\\Users\Admin\Desktop', '.455')
```

Проблема в том, что из за рекурсии не могу просчитать сценарий, когда введенного расширения и файла не существует в директории, этот сценарий выводится многочисленно( к примеру not found выводится очень много раз), а нужно всего лишь единично. Как мне исправить данный дефект?

Comment: В вашем примере нигде не выводится "`not found`". К тому же, рекурсия конечна и ошибок в ней нет.

Comment: Не подскажите, как мне реализовать вывод `Not found` без зацикливания?

Comment: Задача написать именно свой модуль? А то можно однострочником `pathlib.Path(directory).rglob('*' + access)`

Comment: Да, я чисто свой модуль писал. Для практики)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы определить пустоту какой-либо папки, я решил возвращать `True`, если в ней найден файл с нужным расширением.
Таким образом, если функция возвращает `None`, мы можем гарантировать, что все подпапки, которые она парсила, тоже пусты, после чего сделать соответствующий вывод.

***Код:***

```py
import os


def walker(dir, ext):
    for name in os.listdir(dir):
        path = os.path.join(dir, name)

        if os.path.isfile(path):
            f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(path)

            if f_ext == ext:
                print(f'[found] {ext}: {path}')
                return True
        else:
            if not walker(path, ext):
                print(f'[not found] in {path}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    walker(r'C:\Users\Username\Desktop', '.txt')
```

Также я:

- Исправил ошибку, связанную с проверкой расширения *(Ваш код проверяет
  расширение только из 3 символов)*
- Использовал формат-строки для упрощения вывода
- Использовал сырую строку для упрощения передачи директории в функцию
- Удалил неиспользуемые модули из импорта
- Удалил неиспользуемые переменные
- Расставил отступы и абзацы для улучшения читабельности кода

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь! Вызывает вопрос строка `f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(path)`. Я так понял,`f_ext` - это строка с расширением, ничего не путаю?) И еще вопрос к буковке `f` в начале  функции `print()`. Зачем Вы ее использовали и на что она влияет?)

Comment: @PythonLearner4823 Про `f_ext` Вы всё правильно поняли - это расширение файла. Оно может быть разной длины, поэтому я решил использовать специальную функцию для этого. А конструкция `f''` - это формат-строка. Она появилась в Python 3.6 и позволяет очень удобно форматировать строки. Вместо конструкции `{ext}` будет подставлено значение переменной `ext`. Вот привычный аналог: `'[found] {ext}: {path}'.format(ext=ext, path=path)`.

Comment: Ага, понятно. Еще вопросик к строке `if not walker(path, ext):`. Я так понимаю, этот оператор выполняется, если предыдущий не вернул `True`, верно? И разве после `return True` цикл не должен останавливаться?

Comment: @PythonLearner4823 Да, это условие выполняется, если функция `walker` вернёт `None` (так происходит, если вообще не указать `return`, или указать без возвращаемых данных). Это происходит потому что логический оператор `not` инверсирует логический тип. (простыми словами, меняет ложь на истину, а истину на ложь). В Вашем случае `not None` - это истина.

Comment: То есть `if not walker(path, ext)` эквивалентен `if True:`?

Comment: @PythonLearner4823 Смотря что вернёт функция `walker`. Если вернула `None`, то да, эквивалентен `if True:`, а если вернёт `True`, то эквивалентен `if False:`

Comment: Все, теперь понял) Спасибо Вам большое))

Answer (score 1):

[Ответ от @nomnoms12](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/997806/198251) довольно хорош, но не избавил от проблемы вывода огромного числа числа `not found`. Решить это можно несколькими способами.

Вариант 1. Использовать отдельную рекурсивную функцию, а вывод оставить в не-рекурсивной:

```py
import os


def walker(dir, ext):
    def recursive(dir):
        for name in os.listdir(dir):
            path = os.path.join(dir, name)

            if os.path.isfile(path):
                f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(path)
                found = f_ext == ext
            else:
                found = recursive(path)

            if found:
                return True
        return False

    if recursive(dir):
        print(f'[found] {ext}: {dir}')
    else:
        print(f'[not found] {ext} in {dir}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    walker(r'/Users/aivanf/Desktop', '.txt')
```

Того же самого результата можно добиться используя одну функцию с аргументом, который будет отвечать за надобность вывода текста, у которого значение по умолчанию выводит текст, а в рекурсивных вызовах не выводит. Но это не очень красиво.

Обратите внимание, переменная `ext` во вложенную функцию передаётся из контекста внешней функции.

Также стоит отметить, что при рекурсивной реализации получается [поиск в глубину](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83). То есть, если нужный файл лежит в указанной директории, но среди контента это директории он в конце, то сначала будут перебираться все вложенные папки и их содержимое.

---

Вариант 2. Обойдёмся без рекурсии используя простой список. Здесь можно легко реализовать как [поиск в ширину](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83), так и в глубину. Если искомый файл лежит непосредственно в данной директории, то такой поиск будет быстрее.

```py
import os


def walker(dir, ext):
    paths = [dir]
    found = False
    while paths:
        current = paths.pop(0)
        for name in os.listdir(current):
            path = os.path.join(current, name)

            if os.path.isfile(path):
                f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(path)
                if f_ext == ext:
                    print(f'[found] {ext} in {current}')
                    return True
            else:
                # Новые папки добавляем в конец списка,
                # то есть, рассмотрим их после всех файлов.
                paths.append(path)
                # Это поиск в ширину
                # Для поиска в глубину надо просто заменить на `insert`

    print(f'[not found] {ext} in {dir}')
    return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    walker(r'/Users/aivanf/Desktop', '.txt')
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за помощь! Для чего в строке `current = paths.pop(0)` удаляете нулевой элемент? Получается, для `current` вы назначаете значение `dir`. А почему бы не использовать сразу `dir`? Не могли бы Вы объяснить?)

Comment: Потому что помимо `dir` там обрабатываются все остальные директории (благодаря строке `paths.append(path)`) – это типичный обход дерева в ширину. Вообще, когда не хватает абстрактного мышления, чтобы понять работу кода возьмите конкретный пример и визуализируйте каждый шаг алгоритма. Также можно банально воткнуть `print(current)` – сразу станет ясно, что там не только `dir` обрабатывается.